# Scrapy-playwright scraper does not work on Javascript website

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape customer stories from Knime.com. This is the website I want to scrape:
https://www.knime.com/customers

I'm triying to get all of the stories on the website, it's url, title, company name and the content of the story. I tried scrapy splash, but it didnt work. There is a load more button on the page that the script needs to press to load all of the stories. But my code doesnt work. I also did the same think in scrapy playwright, with same result. I'm really frustrated with with all this and would really appreciate it if someone can take a look at my code.

This is the spider from scrapy splash

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class KnimeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'knime'
    start_urls = ['https://www.knime.com/customers']

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='execute',
                            args={'lua_source': self.load_more_lua})  

load_more_lua = """
function main(splash, args)
    splash:go(args.url)
    splash:wait(2)
    for _ = 1, 5 do 
        local load_more_button = splash:evaljs('document.querySelector("#gatsby-focus-wrapper > div > div.px-6.md\\\\:px-14.mb-12.md\\\\:mb-24 > div > div.text-center.mt-10.md\\\\:mt-12.lg\\\\:mt-20 > button")')
        if load_more_button then
            load_more_button:scroll_to()
            load_more_button:mouse_click()
            splash:wait(2)
        end
    end
    splash:wait(2)
    return {html = splash:html()}
end
"""

lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        splash:wait(2)
        return {html = splash:html()}
    end
    """

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.css('div.border.py-1 a[target="_self"]::attr(href)').getall()
    
    for link in links:
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)
        yield SplashRequest(absolute_url, self.parse_customer_story, endpoint='execute',
                            args={'lua_source': self.lua_script})

def parse_customer_story(self, response):
    try:
        title = response.css('title::text').get()
        content = ' '.join(response.css('div.px-6 *::text').getall())
        content = content[:content.rfind('\n')+1]
        img_alt = response.css('div.logo-dots-bg img::attr(alt)').get()
        url = response.url
        yield {'company': img_alt, 'url': url, 'title': title, 'content': content}

    except Exception as e:  
        self.log('Error on %s: %s - Details: %s' % (response.url, type(e), e))
```

and this is from scrapy playwright:

```
import scrapy
from quotes_js_scraper.items import QuoteItem
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://www.knime.com/customers"
    yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'playwright': True,
                                    'playwright_include_page': True,
                                        'playwright_page_method': [
                                        PageMethod('click', '#gatsby-focus-wrapper > div > div.px-6.md\:px-14.mb-12.md\:mb-24 > div > div.text-center.mt-10.md\:mt-12.lg\:mt-20 > button')],
                                    'errback': self.errback
                                    })
async def parse(self, response):
    page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
    screenshot = await page.screenshot(path="example.png", full_page=True)
    await page.close()

    company = response.css('div > div > a > h4::text').getall()
    url = response.css('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > a::attr(href)').getall()
    title = response.css('div > div > div > p::text').get()
    yield {'title': title, 'company': company, 'url': url}
           
async def errback(self, failure):
    page = failure.request.meta['playwright_page']
    await page.close()
```

I am open to any and all suggestions!